# Web app with registration, where each user has a list of notes, using AWS dynamodb, angular, and maybe cognito?

Tags: rest, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

What is the "simplest" way to have a very primitive backend with AWS, where you store information in dynamodb, and users can register, login, logout, and have a list of notes. I'm not sure if I should save the users in dynamodb, or if I should use something like cognito. I know this is a little broad, but I'm not sure which features to use to accomplish this simple app. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way is likely a standard MySQL/PostgreSQL database on an RDS. Chances are very good you won't initially need the complexity of stuff like Dynamo.

Comment: @ceejayoz would I be able to use MySQL/PostgreSQL on an RDS with node, and not php? I'm not really familiar with databases aside for firebase, but am familiar with node, python, es6 and angular

Comment: Sure, it's entirely possible to use SQL with Node.

Answer (score 0):

We have a simple example application that demonstrates many of the things you are highlighting in your question

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-auth-reference-app